# Change a number of products to a product pack

Tags: php, e-commerce

I have this problem : i'm working on a small e-shop and I have about 60 products in the database . all the products have a code , like : 4444, 5334, 3244 and so on . The problem is that there are also product packs and they are made out of several products .

I have to do this : everytime there is an update to the CART there must be a script checking if the products in CART can make a PRODUCT PACK and replace all the products from the CART with that product pack .

What do you think would be the best way to do this check / change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$packs` is an array of arrays of items, and `$cart` is an array of items:

```
foreach($packs as $pack) {
    $diff = array_diff($pack, $cart);
    if (empty($diff)) {
        // $cart contains this pack
    }
}
```

Comment: yes ! great man, thanks ... I still have to figure out how to implement this in my code, but it's great !